# java program not desired outcome

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FtoC 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double DegreesF, DegreesC;
        System.out.print("Enter temperature in Fahrenheit:");
       ` Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        DegreesF = sc.nextInt();
        DegreesC = 5*(DegreesF-32)/9;
        System.out.print(DegreesF + " degrees Fahrenheit" + " is " + DegreesC + " degrees Celsius.");        
    }
}
```

i get the output :Enter temperature in Fahrenheit:72
72.0 degrees Fahrenheit is 22.22222222222222 degrees Celsius.
I need that 72 degrees Fahrenheit to be a whole number, without the decimal part. please help.

Comment: It's a `double`, it will have a decimal point unless you provide a specific format when you print it.  Use `System.out.printf()` instead.

Comment: Nothing changes:(

Comment: Because you didn't specify a format string, Please read the Javadoc for `printf()`

Comment: Hint: In Java variable names should not start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only Scan for an `int` value, simply **define `DegreesF` as an `int`**

```
int DegreesF;
```

rather than

```
double DegreesF;
```

since `Integers` don't have a decimal point you won't have the problem any more

to get correct Celcius value do this:

```
DegreesC = 5*((double)DegreesF-32)/9;
```

Comment: I tried this method before.I  switched DegreesF to double because in the output it would give me 22.0 Celsius instead of 22.2222

Comment: you need to cast it in the calculation `DegreesC = 5*((double)DegreesF-32)/9;`

Answer (score 0):

> I need that 72 degrees Fahrenheit to be a whole number, without the
>   decimal part

You could store it initially as an `int`, and not a `double`:

```
int DegreesF;
double DegreesC;
```

Which will print:

> 72 degrees Fahrenheit is 22.0 degrees Celsius.

Or cast it as an `int` in your print statement:

```
System.out.print((int)DegreesF + " degrees...
```

Although better to go with the first way.

Also, you should then specify the Celsius value (perhaps to two decimal points):

One way would be to use `DecimalFormat`:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
```

and print it like:

```
df.format(DegreesC)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was thinking to print (int)DegreesF, wasn't sure if i could actually do that. The other method still doesn't give me the desired outcome. Maybe that's just too advanced for me at the moment since i only had 2 classes, i am a beginner.